Parsing structured log from a container by google cloud ops agent
I have an application running inside a container inside a GCP vm, outputting log that looks like this: {"severity":"INFO","message":"Http request served","timestamp":{"seconds":1712394651,"nanos":76426063},"httpRequest":{"requestMethod":"GET","requestUrl":"/health","requestSize":"0","responseSize":"0","userAgent":"curl/7.76.1","latency":"0","referer":""}}
I want this log to be parsed correctly as json, so is visible with the relevant fields inside the GCP log explorer.
However, I seem unable to achieve this, as the metadata emitted from the transport mechanism is the "structure" and my log output from the application is always treated as unstructured text.
To export the logs, I've tried docker gcp logging driver (directly to gcp), docker fluent logging driver with ops-agent, and docker journald logging driver with ops-agent. Ops-agent has parse_json processor always enabled.
logging:
  receivers:
    rec-v1:
      type: fluent_forward
      listen_port: 24224
    rec-v1-journald:
      type: systemd_journald
  processors:
    rec-v1-processor:
      type: parse_json
  service:
    pipelines:
      default_pipeline:
        receivers: []
      tokenz_backend_v1:
        receivers:
          - rec-v1
          - rec-v1-journald
        processors: [v1-processor]

but the logs always end up unparsed as text.
With fluent transport, it ends up in the log field inside the jsonPayload (as specified here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/fluentd/)
with journald transport, it ends up in the MESSAGE field.
How to have it parsed correctly as json?
Edit: clarity
Update: I've exposed TCP receiver on 172.17.0.1 (host ip address from docker), and redirected stdout from my app into that socket. Now it works as intended, skipping all the docker logging driver and all the protocol middlemen -- I'm still curious why my logs were treated as text, not json.

Have you gone through this documentation? once go through this documentation and check whether you have followed all the configurations as per this documentation.
